# changing fillColor of an area on click using Jquery maphilight plugin

Tags: jquery, dictionary, highlight

I am using JQuery maphilight plugin to highlight the areas in the world map. Right now I have set the following default options for the area elements

```
fillColor: 'F25607' //orange color
alwaysOn:  'true'
```

So that on pageload the area elements are colored with orange. I have an onclick event for each of the area elements.
I need to change the highlight color (i.e. the fillColor) of the clicked area element in the map to a different color like green
when I click another element in the map that element should change to green and the previous selected element should change back to orange.
Here is sample code of my map

```
<img id="theImg" class="map" src="/gra/images/worldblank.png" usemap="#worldmap" />
<map id="worldmap" name="worldmap">
      <area class='area' shape="circle" alt="Israel" title="Israel" coords="423,232,7" href="#" onclick="loadActivity('Israel');" />
      <area class='area' shape="circle" alt="China" title="China" coords="548,229,5" href="#" onclick="loadActivity('China');"  />
</map>
```

the sample js function to be completed would be :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.map').maphilight();
    });

$(function() {
  $('.area').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); // from the samples, i guess used to overrride default options
// get the clicked area element and set its fillColor to green 
// make the previous selected area fillColor to the default options value  (if we need to do this)
// use the trigger function to trigger this change
    });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hope this help you:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.area').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).data(maphilight) || {};
    data.fillColor = 'FF0000'; // Sample color

    // This sets the new data, and finally checks for areas with alwaysOn set
    $(this).data('maphilight', data).trigger(alwaysOn.maphilight);
  });
});
</script>
```

Source: [Example from the official documentation](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html).

Comment: This worked for me when I changed to .trigger('alwaysOn.maphilight') with apostrophes around the argument.

Answer (score -2):

Its so simple, go to this link
http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/
then open up your jquery.maphilight.min.js file and change the fill colour to whatever color code you like.
Hope this worked !